# bootstrap-datapicker не открывается с первого раза jquery + input

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

Всем привет) прошу помощи. Есть баг. У нас есть форма (input text), по классу с помощью jquery вешается datepicker (bootstrap-datapicker). Он вызывается и работает. Все ок. Если выбрать дату, а потом нажать на поле еще раз, то datapicker снова появится и дату можно поменять. Но если в момент когда datapicker активирован, нажать просто где в стороне на любой элемент. ТО тогда при нажатии снова на инпут, datapicker не открывается с первого раза. Нужно нажимать на соседний инпут например, а потом снова на нужный инпут. Кто-нибудь сталкивался?

```
<form class="form-horizontal right-form">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputWhen" class="col-sm-2 control-label tuda">Туда</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <input type="text" readonly style="cursor: pointer;" class="form-control datepicker" id="inputWhen">

                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="checker squaredFour">
                          <label>
                            <input class="checkbox checkdva" type="checkbox" name="checkbox-test" data-class="js-a">
                            <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
                        </label>
                        </div>


                        <label for="inputReturn" class="col-sm-2 control-label obratno">Обратно</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <input type="text" readonly style="cursor: pointer;" class="form-control datepicker js-all js-a" id="inputReturn" disabled>

                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <a class="button-link-ticket" href="#"><div class="button-ticket">НАЙТИ БИЛЕТЫ</div></a>              
                    </form>
```

Выше html, а вызывается datepicker через jquery

```
    $('#inputWhen').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                weekStart: 1,
                maxViewMode: 2,
                todayBtn: "linked",
                language: "ru",
                orientation: "top auto",
                toggleActive: false
            });

    $('#inputReturn').datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        weekStart: 1,
        maxViewMode: 2,
        todayBtn: "linked",
        language: "ru",
        orientation: "top auto",
        toggleActive: false
    });
```

Comment: Проверил с datepicker 1.7.1 в пределах указанного кода все работает

Comment: именно моя проблема? Сам по себе datapicker работает. Проблема только в том, что не срабатывает по первому клику повторный вызов пикера, если перед этим кликнул на другую область или поскроллил экран.

Comment: Значит проблема в JS-коде, который вы _не показали_

Comment: А можете подсказать что можно сделать.. вообщем я заметил, что если кликнуть на любой другой элемент, а потом снова на инпут, то все прекрасно работает. Получается, что нужно как-бы поменять "активный" элемент.  А если нажимать на инпут постоянно, то снова вызов функции не происходит. МОжет вы подскажете. Написать какую-нибудь функцию, чтобы например когда исчезает датапикер (становится неактивным), происходило "обновление класса" или что-то вроде этого. Я понимаю что сформулировал абстрактно, но вы меня поняли наверное. Спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрите по коду и в "инструментах" какие обработчики висят на этих инпутах

Comment: Не совсем понял. На инпутах которые я сверстал? там айди, к которым  такая конструкция $('#inputWhen').datepicker() применяется

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72501/discussion-between-tutankhamun-and-alex-sorokin).